# Handling Categorical Data unit and numerical Data Together

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, categorical-data, feature-selection

I have Dataframe Having 3 Feature Product_detail,S.I_Units and Value.

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Product_detail': ['XYZ', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'],'D': ['g', 'Kg', 'l', 'ml'],'F': ['500', '1', '1', '1000']} )
```

My `Product_detail` Column Containing Text So I have Converted it into `TfidfVectorizer`

I have to Calculate Similarity Matrix, But I am Not getting  any Idea How to use
`S.I_units` Column Together with `Value` Column., Let Say for example some row of DataFrame is like ('Amul Butter', 'g' , '200') , ('Amul Butter', 'g' , '100'), ('Amul Butter', 'g' , '300') , ('Amul Milk', 'ml' , '1000'). I want top 'n' Similar Product Product for Amul Butter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your expected output is but you can do something with `fuzzywuzzy` which is a percent str match:

let's assume this df:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Product_detail': ['butter', 'amul butter', 'amul milk', 'milk'],'D': ['g', 'Kg', 'l', 'ml'],'F': ['500', '1', '1', '1000']})


Product_detail  D   F
0   butter      g   500
1   amul butter Kg  1
2   amul milk   l   1
3   milk        ml  1000
```

then you can create a list of choices and use process.extract()

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process

# create a list of choices from df['Product_detail']
choices = list(df4['Product_detail'].values)

# use fuzzywuzzy's process.extract()
# limit is the number of returned results
process.extract('amul butter', choices, limit=3)
```

out:

```
[('amul butter', 100), ('butter', 90), ('amul milk', 59)]
```

if you do not want the percent match then do list comprehension:

```
result = process.extract('amul butter', choices, limit=3)

# list comprehension to remove the percent
[x[0] for x in result]
```

out:

```
['amul butter', 'butter', 'amul milk']
```

if you want to return your df:

```
# list comprehension to remove the percent
result_list = [x[0] for x in result]

# if you want to return your df
df4[df4['Product_detail'].isin(result_list)]

    Product_detail  D   F
0   butter          g   500
1   amul butter     Kg  1
2   amul milk       l   1
```